# Insert variable value into a list - python

Tags: python, pygame

I'm developing a Snake Game and I'm having a real trouble with the Tail. The code I created should works, but there's some problems with the list and the variable I used.

At the beginning of the program, I declared 2 lists:

```
playerpos=[552,352]
snake=[]
```

When I move the snake, the playerpos increases or decreases of 50.
Then I insert the list "playerpos" at position 0 of the list "snake

```
snake.insert(0,playerpos)
```

I print the snake head

```
screen.blit(serpente,snake[0])
pygame.display.flip #upgrade the screen
```

And so the rest of the program:

```
    if prevscore==score:
        del snake[0]
    elif prevscore<score:
        prevscore+=1
    for i in range(0,score):
        screen.blit(tail,snake[i])
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Now I use this code to see if the snake ate an apple.
If he did, I don't do anything. If he didn't I just delete the first element of the list (to keep the same length of the snake)

Then I start a "for cycle" to print the snake tail.

I expect that it appears the tail, but it doesn't. I debugged my program and I found out that when I change the value of "playerpos", all the "snake" list changes.
It's look like it isn't

```
snake=[[value took from playerpos] , [value took from playerpos] , [value took from playerpos]]
```

but it's more like

```
snake=[playerpos, playerpos, playerpos]
```

So when I change the playerpos value to move my snake, the entire snake list changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`playerpos=[552,352]` is a list. You've to create a shallow copy of the player position:

```py
snake.insert(0, playerpos[:])
```

Note, in python a variable name is a reference to an object. The data is contained in the object. When you do an assignment, then the reference is assigned and both variables refer to the same object.

When you do

> ```py
> snake.insert(0, playerpos)
> ```

then a reference to the object behind the name `playerpos` is inserted into the list. At the end all elements of the list refer to the same object. So if you change the content of `playerpos`, then all the elements seems to be magically changed, too.

`[:]` crates a shallow  copy of a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html). So a reference to a copy of the list (`playerpos`) is inserted.